# How do I connect to a website with the Python requests module, through a proxy?

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests

I'm trying to connect to a website through a proxy. The proxy itself is working, but you can use another one to test it.

```
import requests

proxy = {'http': 'http://219.92.3.149:8080', 'https': 'https://219.92.3.149:8080'}

print(requests.get("https://httpbin.org/ip", proxies=proxy).text)
```

The interpreter throws the following error, why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

`requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='httpbin.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /ip (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1123)')))`

Comment: Why are you writing your title in ALL CAPS? Are you trying to hurt my eyes? :)

Comment: I tested your code, it works fine on my computer (with the exception of a bad proxy)

Comment: Give me the good proxy you used then, it's impossible my proxy works.

Comment: Weird. I'm getting the same error as OP with my localhost proxy. Works in curl, but not in python. `curl -v` says "SSL certificate verify ok."